# How to pass variable to cpack?

Tags: cmake, cpack

I have a cmake project which one of the install targets is a collection of files. This files change depending on the configuration (Release, Debug...).
I would like to be able to install the files like so:

```
install(DIRECTORY $<TARGET_FILE_DIR:tgt>
    DESTINATION bin
    COMPONENT files)
```

But cmake does not support that. Generator variables do not apply to DIRECTORY. So I was wondering if there is a way to either save the directory somewhere. Either the cache or a file and then load it into cpack.

So I guess the question is how to pass a variable from cmake to cpack?

Comment: According to `install` [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/command/install.html#installing-directories), only `DESTINATION` option can use *generator expressions*, `DIRECTORY` option **cannot use them**.

Comment: @Tsyvarev yeah I know that. Do you have any idea to fix my problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a rather late answer, but I happened upon this question trying to solve a somewhat different problem that could also be summarized as: "How do I pass a variable to CPack?" In my case, I was making this call from a customized version of `CPackDeb.cmake` copied to my workspace:

```
find_program(OPKG_CMD NAMES opkg-build HINTS "${OPKG_HINT}")
#                                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^
#                                 This is what I wanted to pass to CPack
```

I was setting `OPKG_HINT` in a file included from my top-level `CMakeLists.txt`, but it was not getting passed through to `cpack`; the above `find_program()` invocation was seeing an empty string for `OPKG_HINT`.

The solution turned out to be *stupid* simple: just prepend `CPACK_` to the variable name!

If I do this in `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
set(CPACK_OPKG_HINT "${_sysroot_top}/aarch64-poky-linux/usr/bin")
```

then I can put this in my `CPackDeb.cmake` file and it works fine:

```
find_program(OPKG_CMD NAMES opkg-build HINTS "${CPACK_OPKG_HINT}")
```

Anyway, this wound up being a bit of an [X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) for the OP, but... if you *really* need to set a variable at CMake time in such a way that it's accessible to `cpack`, prefixing the variable name with `CPACK_` seems to do the trick nicely...

Comment: Thanks for that answer.. I was struggling alot. This works

Comment: Do you have a reference for this in CMAKE's/CPACK's documentation? Or might this be just an implementation detail (I'd rather not depend on those)?

Comment: @ricab, I couldn't find anything in the docs, so I asked about it on the CMake Discourse Forum: https://discourse.cmake.org/t/why-are-cpack-variables-documented-in-two-different-places/1525/4.  Brad King of Kitware replied that "it should be stable behavior", so... I guess it's safe to depend on this.

Answer (score 2):

The following setup work if you use a "single-configuration generators (such as make and Ninja)" and call CMake with

```
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release <source_dir>
```

https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/variable/CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE.html

You can define the `${dir}` variable in another way if you like.

```
IF (CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE STREQUAL "Release")
    SET(dir release_dir)
ELSE()
    SET(dir debug_dir)
ENDIF()

INSTALL(DIRECTORY ${dir} DESTINATION bin COMPONENT files)
```

Answer (score 2):

CMake 3.5 supports generator expressions for the `DIRECTORY` arguments. See [installing directories](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.5/command/install.html#installing-directories).

Answer (score 2):

Until now this seems to be the best answer (from someone on the cmake mail list)

```
install(DIRECTORY path/to/Debug/dir
  DESTINATION bin
  CONFIGURATIONS Debug
  COMPONENT files
)

install(DIRECTORY path/to/Release/dir
  DESTINATION bin
  CONFIGURATIONS Release
  COMPONENT files
)
```